# Strongloop - update with ajax

Tags: ajax, node.js, strongloop

I try to perform an update with ajax on my db but it's not working.

Url i tried :

http://localhost:8880/api/Tracks/update?filter{"id ": "1"}

What i get :

> {
>     "error": {
>       "name": "AssertionError",
>       "status": 500,
>       "message": "The where argument must be an object",
>       "actual": false,
>       "expected": true,
>       "operator": "==",
>       "generatedMessage": false,

}
}

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try for this:

```
curl -X PUT --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "{
  //your data here
}" "http://localhost:aaaa/xx/yy/%7B%22id%22%3A1%7D"
```